# Scale a screenshot of pygame screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a program that can guess a handwritten digit using the mnist dataset and pygame. When trying to scale a screenshot of my window I get an error. Any ideas?
Here is the error in `screenshot = pygame.transform.scale(screenshot,(28,28))`:

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None
```

Code:

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
size = x, y = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screenshot = pygame.image.save(screen, "screenshot.jpeg")
screenshot = pygame.transform.scale(screenshot,(28,28))
```

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue and should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out). Also, a scaling a screenshot question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Ok thank you sorry I'm a new user

Comment: `pygame.transform.scale` scales a pygame surface. You don't have any pygame surface here, you just save a jpg image.

Comment: No problem, just keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: So is there even a way to take a screenshot and scale it to 28 * 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invert the order of your two last lines. First scale the screen: you'll get the scaled `pygame.Surface` (you won't see anything in your display since you are not blitting it). Then save the surface on the disk.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
size = x, y = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

screenshot = pygame.transform.scale(screen,(28,28))
pygame.image.save(screenshot, "screenshot.jpeg")
```

This simple example will give you a black 28x28 image, since nothing is drawn on it before.